# Help regarding SLME calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, spectroscopy, solar-cells

Information 
Paper - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1566119918302787 
Github Link - https://github.com/ldwillia/SL3ME

Question - I have been studying solar cell materials. I am computing their properties. One of the part of calculations will be to calculate Spectroscopic Limited Maximum Efficiency (SLME). Can you help me with its process steps? 
Assuming - The absorbance data is to be taken from optical calculations.  
So far I have tried it with the example in the link and got the following error. 
Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/slme/SL3ME.py", line 127, in <module>
    SLME =  calculate_SLME( material_eV_for_absorbance_data = material_eV_for_absorbance_data,
  File "/home/slme/SL3ME.py", line 14, in calculate_SLME
    from numpy import sys, loadtxt, pi,  exp, zeros, linspace
ImportError: cannot import name 'sys' from 'numpy' (/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py)
```

Comment: try to remove importing sys from numpy, I don't think there is a module called sys in numpy, as sys is supposed to be from the std library. sys is being imported for handling the error of not finding the .dat file in the working directory, you can try to adsjust the script, move that import from numpy and make it 'import sys'

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I removed "from numpy" and then later further down the script it says - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slme/SL3ME.py", line 123, in <module>
    import loadtxt, arange, logspace
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loadtxt'

Comment: I think you may want to write your own script for this. From looking at the linked script and based on your comments, it contains numerous errors or pieces that have fallen out of sync in the 6 years since it was written. You might be able to extract the scientifically relevant parts and write it as more idiomatic Python (or any other programming language you might know).

Comment: @epsilon02fft, that's not what I meant you to do, I said you can either remove 'sys' from the importing line or move it somewhere else. You can just replace that line 'from numpy import sys, loadtxt, pi,  exp, zeros, linspace' with 'from numpy import loadtxt, pi,  exp, zeros, linspace'. As far as all the required files are in the working directory where you are running the script then there would be no error to be handled and you won't need 'sys'. Yet as Tyberius mention, the script is quite old and other things might be broken as well. you can give it a try.

Comment: @Tyberius Yes, thank you. I figured that out after getting the error issues that the script needs upgrade and I did that as best as I could. I was able to find the output, I just need to confirm if my process and data output is correct or not now.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Yes, I understood. Thank you, I have upgraded the script itself. As I added import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
... etc for it to work with certain other changes and additions which solved the problem. Now I need to confirm if the data output and process is correct or not.

Comment: @epsilon02fft, great! If you get a positive confirm for your method, you can come back and add an answer to your question for others who might have similar problem.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Yes, I will. Its just the script part is done for now. I really need to understand certain parts such as direct allowed band gap - fundamental band gap and how to calculate voltages vs E from this method. Lot to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The steps here which worked for me regarding this particular script

1. At the start of the script add required libraries, such as (you can change according to your requirement)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
... (other required libraries)
```

2. Then change the script accordingly.
3. Make sure the Energy is in $\mathrm{eV}$ and the absorption is in $\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ (it should technically be in $\mathrm{m}^{-1}$).
4. Put minimum value of the band gap of your structure for - `material_direct_allowed_gap`, `material_indirect_gap`
5. Change values of thickness and temperature to get SLME values at your required data values.
6. A logarithmic plot of thickness vs SLME can be plotted for analysis now.

Good luck! Hope it works for you as well as me, I hope there are no problems here. If I find any, I will update. You are welcome to update as well so that I can also learn and change.

Comment: Are you sure about point 4? If you set both of the variables as the same value, then `delta = material_direct_allowed_gap - material_indirect_gap = 0` always! Also the GitHub script says to use the keyword argument `absorbance_in_inverse_centimeters=True` or `False` depending on the unit. The default is `False`. In any case, since the code is only of around 150 lines, it would be great if you can add your corrected version as well in the end.